# Display count in the textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

My goal to my code is to show the count query for the number of batchcode in table batchcodes to my textbox and if i click the button it will save to the batchcode table...my batchcode field is

'id','batchcode'

my current code:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include('include/connect.php');

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT count(batchcode) FROM batchcodes";
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$var = $query+1;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO batchcodes(batchcode) VALUES ('$var')";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php" >
<input type="text" value="batch<?php echo $query; ?>" />

<input type="submit" name"save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my code im suffering from error like Undefined variable query and warning mysql_fetch_array expects parameter 1...I need your help guys.

Comment: You have to *execute* the query before you *fetch* results from it.

Comment: 1. Execute your query. 2. You will get result in `$rows`. 3. **mysql_*** functions are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

Comment: please mention you need to insert textbox value or query result.  The query result single value or long array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql_query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT count(batchcode) AS nb_batchcode FROM batchcode"); 
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $batchcode=$row['nb_batchcode'];
}

<input type="text" name="save" value="batch<?php echo $batchcode; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql_query function to execute the query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT count(batchcode) as batchcode FROM batchcodes");

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO batchcodes(batchcode) VALUES (". $var .")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it on PHP based on my SQL data

```
<li>
                <label> OR #: </label>
                <?php
                include('php/connect-db.php');
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(or_num)+1 AS inc_or FROM tbl_admission");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $nextOR=$row['inc_or'];
                }
                ?>

                <input type="text" name="asID" value="<?php echo $nextOR; ?>" disabled>
```

OR_num is my integer and auto-incremented key in my table "tbl_admission" :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `$row`  instead of `$query` to get result from query.Try below code can help you.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include('include/connect.php');

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT count(batchcode) as batchcode FROM batchcodes";
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $var = $row[0] + 1;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO batchcodes(batchcode) VALUES (". $var .")";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php" >
<input type="text" name="save" value="batch<?php echo $query; ?>" />

<input type="submit"
</form>
</body>
</html>
```